# How to select an object and move camera into to another position?

Tags: three.js

I have a problem I don't known how I can select the position of the selected inside scene and move camera into it

I found a project sample, and I want to build an example like it

[Sample project](https://showroom.littleworkshop.fr)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You basically solve this problem in two steps:

First, you have to make 3D objects selectable which can be done via raycasting. There are many official examples that demonstrate 3D interaction based on raycasting, for example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_cubes

If you know that a certain 3D object was clicked, you animate the camera from its current position to a defined target position. The possible target positions can be defined prior or you compute the in some way on the fly based on the object's bounding volume and the current camera position. The actual animation can be done in many ways. One approach is using a tweening engine like [tween.js](https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/). Check out the following example to see how it is used together with `three.js`:

https://threejs.org/examples/css3d_periodictable

Comment: Thank you, how I select a position on floor, and move camera lookat with select point with mouse?
I only a 3d model by using gltfloader and it's model house design

Comment: I want select any position and move camera into it.
exp: https://www.mcdonaldjoneshomes.com.au/bridgetown-3d-walk-through

Comment: When you implement the interaction via raycasting, you can use the intersection point provided by [Raycaster.intersectObject](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject) to compute the new position for the camera. You just have to add a defined height to the `y` property of the position vector so the camera does not move to the floor.

Comment: Thank for your support, I have a problem when render my obj model. ceiling lights not render, I have tried light type for examples in threejs but not resolved my issues, can you help me?

Comment: In this case, it's best to answer a new question at stackoverflow or the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/).